# Android SDK licences not been accepted

Tags: android, sdk

I would like run my React-Native project using Docker container. I use [this image](https://github.com/stephane-r/react-native-docker) for run my project.

After successfully build my Docker image, android return an error :

`Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.`

But all licence are accepted ... :

[image]

I don't really understand why i've this error.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !